# Handling Collection data in NSMutable Array in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting "JSON Data" from "WebServices" and setting them in `NSMutableArray` and trying to get to show in a Page, I am using "4 Keys" as per "JSON Data" but I don't Know how to use "Key-value" to get particular data from the `NSMutableArray`, My "JSON` Data" is like this -

More

3 of 5,641

JSON ARRAY FORMAT
Inbox
    x
anuj jha

9:13 PM (14 hours ago)

to me, Gaurav, RAjeev

<__NSArrayM 0x7f9e42556c10>(

```
{

    ansDesc = "Researching a lead that I previously submitted ";

    ansId = 1;

    qsDesc = "What is your primary goal for visiting the portal, today? ";

    qsId = 1;

},

{

    ansDesc = "Submitting a new lead ";

    ansId = 2;

    qsDesc = "What is your primary goal for visiting the portal, today? ";

    qsId = 1;

},

{

    ansDesc = "Working on a draft lead ";

    ansId = 3;

    qsDesc = "What is your primary goal for visiting the portal, today? ";

    qsId = 1;

},

{

    ansDesc = "Daily ";

    ansId = 4;

    qsDesc = "How often do you use the Target Revenue Portal? ";

    qsId = 2;

},

{

    ansDesc = "Several times a week ";

    ansId = 5;

    qsDesc = "How often do you use the Target Revenue Portal? ";

    qsId = 2;

},

{

    ansDesc = "Once a week ";

    ansId = 6;

    qsDesc = "How often do you use the Target Revenue Portal? ";

    qsId = 2;

},

{

    ansDesc = "Every couple of weeks ";

    ansId = 7;

    qsDesc = "How often do you use the Target Revenue Portal? ";

    qsId = 2;

},

{

    ansDesc = "About once a month ";

    ansId = 8;

    qsDesc = "How often do you use the Target Revenue Portal? ";

    qsId = 2;

},
```

I have to show only set of question and corresponding answers of "qsId 1" and "ansId 1, 2, 3" together in the page and then similarly for "qsId 2" with "ansId 4,5,6,7,8" in the next page. Please help me to figure out the most feasible way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C, `NSMutableArray` doesn't support key-value concept. `NSDictionary` does support it.

The better way in my mind is using a model class to hold the four properties and use the `NSPredicate` to filter them out.

```
@interface JSON_Info : NSObject

//id's
@property (nonatomic, assign) int qsId;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int ansId;

//descriptions
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *qsDesc;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ansDesc; 

@end
```

If you want to filter it, use `NSPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"qsId == 1 && ansId == 2"];
NSArray *filteredCollection = [self.JSONInfoCollection filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try typing the following code in your program:

```
NSMutableArray yourData = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dic in jSON) {
   [yourData addObject:dic];
}
```

**Now you can accses the value by key, no object by key:**

```
someLabel.text = [yourData valueForKey:ansDesc]; // just an example
```